# Backpack for Laravel - how to display colored rectangle column for color_picker field?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, color-picker, laravel-backpack

I'm currently facing a challenge to display a color picker value in one of my CRUDs in backpack for laravel. One of my CRUDs is having a color attribute and I'm using a color_picker field when creating a new entry.

I don't want to display just the string value of the selected color, I want to display a rectangle containing the selected color, something like this (Farbe = color):

[image]

I've tried the following things already:

```
CRUD::addColumn([
        'name'     => 'color',
        'label'    => 'Farbe',
        'type'     => 'custom_html',
        'value' => '<svg width="20" height="20">
                        <rect width="20" height="20" style="fill:'. $this->crud->getCurrentEntry()->color . ';" />
                    </svg>',
        'escaped' => false, //optional, if the "value" should be escaped when displayed in the page.
    ]);
```

But it didn't work, most likely because the getCurrentEntry method is not available in the setupListOperation.

Then I tried it with a model_function:

```
CRUD::addColumn([
        // run a function on the CRUD model and show its return value
        'name'  => 'color',
        'label' => 'Farbe', // Table column heading
        'type'  => 'model_function',
        'function_name' => 'getColorRectangle',
        //'attribute' => 'route' // the method in your Model
        // 'function_parameters' => [$one, $two], // pass one/more parameters to that method
        // 'limit' => 100, // Limit the number of characters shown
    ]);
```

with this function in the model:

```
public function getColorRectangle()
{
    return "<svg width='400' height='110'>
                <rect width='300' height='100' style='fill:" . $this->color . ";stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)'></rect>
            </svg>";
}
```

But again, unfortunately without success.

Happy for any suggestions, maybe I'm already blind after struggling for several hours on this topic.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would rather [create a custom column type](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-columns#creating-a-custom-column-type) for that. That has quite a few benefits:

- easier to debug;
- the HTML code is in a Blade file;
- you can re-use this column type any time you want, in a different CrudController;

And it's super-easy to do. See [the docs here]([create a custom column type](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-columns#creating-a-custom-column-type)) but in your particular case it would be something like this:

**Step 1.** Create a `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/columns/color.blade.php` file.

**Step 2.** In that file, copy-paste your HTML code but use `$entry->{$column['name']}` to get the value of that column:

```php
<svg width="20" height="20">
     <rect width="20" height="20" style="fill:'. $entry->{$column['name']} . ';" />
</svg>
```

**Step 3.** Use this new column inside your CrudController

```php
CRUD::addColumn([
    'name'     => 'color',
    'label'    => 'Farbe',
    'type'     => 'color',
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your second method and it works, but you need to add `limit` to your column, so your code will be like this:

```
CRUD::addColumn([
        // run a function on the CRUD model and show its return value
        'name'  => 'color',
        'label' => 'Farbe', // Table column heading
        'type'  => 'model_function',
        'function_name' => 'getColorRectangle',
        'limit' => 2000,
    ]);
```

The problem is your custom value not show because limited by default from backpack list.